# Problem with the connection with Instagram using Instagram4j in Java

Tags: java, instagram

I am trying of do login, in localhost is OK, but in the serve (AWS), It isn't doing login.
I have a method for do login and save the login in a cookie.txt file, If I need the login, find the cookie file for don't do login again

My code for do login is the next:

```
protected Instagram4j login(Instagram4j instagram){
  try {
    instagram.setup();
    instagram.login();

    File cookiesFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + FILE_COOKIES);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(cookiesFile));
    oos.writeObject(instagram.getCookieStore());
    oos.close();
  } catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return instagram;
}
```

For verify the cookies:

```
protected Instagram4j checkLogin(Instagram4j instagram){
    Instagram4j instagram2 = null;

    try {
      // Open de cookies in the .txt
      ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + FILE_COOKIES));
      CookieStore cookieStore = (CookieStore) ois.readObject();
      ois.close();

      // Verify the session
      instagram2 = Instagram4j.builder().username(INSTAGRAM_USERNAME)
        .password(INSTAGRAM_PASSWORD)
        .uuid(instagram.getUuid())
        .cookieStore(cookieStore)
        .build();
      instagram2.setup();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.getMessage();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      e.getMessage();
    }

    return instagram2;
}
```

For call the method:

```
Instagram4j instagramLogin = Instagram4j.builder().username(INSTAGRAM_USERNAME).password(INSTAGRAM_PASSWORD).build(); 
Instagram4j instagram = (checkLogin(instagramLogin) == null) ? login(instagramLogin) : checkLogin(instagramLogin);
```

The error in the serve is this:

```
2020-03-16 12:02:36.640 INFO 18541 --- [task-scheduler-10] o.brunocvcunha.instagram4j.Instagram4j : Setup...

2020-03-16 12:02:36.640 INFO 18541 --- [task-scheduler-10] o.brunocvcunha.instagram4j.Instagram4j : Device ID is: android-547cbdeb2f1634d4, random id: c8c30455-72fd-4a0e-a396-5c5d2e422092

2020-03-16 12:02:36.641 INFO 18541 --- [task-scheduler-10] o.brunocvcunha.instagram4j.Instagram4j : Setup...

2020-03-16 12:02:36.641 INFO 18541 --- [task-scheduler-10] o.brunocvcunha.instagram4j.Instagram4j : Device ID is: android-547cbdeb2f1634d4, random id: fad1e2c1-61e8-4c13-a642-320b402ce74a

2020-03-16 12:02:36.641 INFO 18541 --- [task-scheduler-10] o.brunocvcunha.instagram4j.Instagram4j : Sending request: org.brunocvcunha.instagram4j.requests.InstagramSearchUsernameRequest

**2020-03-16 12:02:36.973 INFO 18541 --- [task-scheduler-10] o.b.i.requests.InstagramRequest : Reading InstagramSearchUsernameResult from {"message": "login_required", "error_title": "You've Been Logged Out", "error_body": "Please log back in.", "logout_reason": 2,**
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to complete the verification process

https://github.com/instagram4j/instagram4j/pull/358